# How to speed up this loop reading PDF files in .Net Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, spire.pdf

I have this method `SearchPdf(string path, string keyword)` where `path` is the folder path that contains all the PDFs file to search and `keyword` is the keyword to search in the PDF file or PDF's file name.
I'm using `Spire.Pdf` to read the PDFs.

Here is the method:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchPdf(string path, string keyword)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var files = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        // Apri il file PDF
        var document = new PdfDocument(file.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\rRicerca per: " + keyword + " in file: " + file.Name + "\n\r");

        // Itera le pagine del documento
        for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            // Estrai il testo della pagina
            var page = document.Pages[i];
            var text = page.ExtractText();

            // Cerca la parola chiave
            keyword = keyword.ToLower().Trim();
            if (text.ToLower().Contains(keyword) || file.Name.ToLower().Trim().Contains(keyword) || file.FullName.ToLower().Trim().Contains(keyword))
            {
                results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyword, file.FullName));
            }
        }
    });

    return results;
}
```

All works fine but when I have more than 200 keywords to search and more then 1500 files it's a bit slow. Is there something to do to optimize this loop?

Comment: You should find which line has most impact on performance. I could suggest to remove `ToLower()` and replace is with `text.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. 
This check is a lot faster than `ToLower()`, like 250 times. You can check it in this [article](https://rhale78.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/string-equality-and-performance-in-c/). Also make benchmark, so you know you are increasing performance and not the opposite.

Comment: For this kind of search (many keywords in many files) you could implement a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It's not trivial but super fast.

Comment: If you think about it your approach will always be `O(f*c*k)` where `f` is the number of files, `c` is the (average) number of characters to search per file, and `k` is the number of keywords. Parallelization and micro optimizations can only get you so far. If you want orders of magnitudes faster, you'll need a completely different approach.

Comment: BTW Spire.PDF comes with built-in search functionality: [`Page.FindText()`](https://www.e-iceblue.com/api_documents/5e4e0b69721393-11731598/res/html/643aaa49-af5d-f682-88c7-eb8f9a3bb8f2.htm). Have you tried it yet? I would assume it's faster then extracting all the text first.

Comment: It seem like `Page.FindText()` supports regular expressions so you could try to combine all your keywords into a giant regex of the form `"keyword1|keyword2|..." and search for all of them at once.

Comment: How many items you usually received while process each request? Did you tried the solution provided? Any performance imporvement have you gain.

Answer (score 1):

> I have more than 200 keywords

And you loading all pdfs and processing for every single one of them. I think it would be much more efficient to load file once and check it for all keywords:

```cs
public static ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchPdf(string path, string[] keywords)
{
    //...
    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        // ...
        for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var keyword in keywords)
            {
                // search for keyword and add it to the results    
            }
        }
    }
    // ...  
}
```

Next thing you can try to optimize - break of search for page/keyword pair - since you care only about keyword being found in file not a page - break out earlier if the keyword was found (and/or all keywords were found), for example by maintaining local hashset of found keywords.

Then optimize the search (as suggested in comments) - no need create bunch of string by using `ToLower` and add pressure on the GC -

Instead of

```cs
keyword = keyword.ToLower().Trim();
if (text.ToLower().Contains(keyword) || file.Name.ToLower().Trim().Contains(keyword) || file.FullName.ToLower().Trim().Contains(keyword))
{
    results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyword, file.FullName));
}
```

just use:

```
if (text.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || file.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || file.FullName.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyword, file.FullName));
}
```

Also possibly perform file name and full file name checks before the fulltext search (maybe before file/page load).

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are only interested in the filename you should stop processing pages after the first occurrence.
2. Do not open and extract the pdf if the keyword already matches the filename.
3. Use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase to compare strings instead of calling ToLower.

```
public static ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchPdf(string path, string keyword)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var files = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        if(file.Name.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 || 
           file.FullName.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyword, file.FullName));
        }
        else 
        {
            // Apri il file PDF
            var document = new PdfDocument(file.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\rRicerca per: " + keyword + " in file: " + file.Name + "\n\r");

            // Itera le pagine del documento
            for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
            {
                // Estrai il testo della pagina
                var page = document.Pages[i];
                var text = page.ExtractText();

                if (text.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyword, file.FullName));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return results;
}
```